# Peeking inside the chrome protocol in Firefox

Tags: firefox, protocols, gecko

I was wondering whether it is possible to look inside the input stream 
when the "chrome://" protocol is used in Firefox. Let me be more 
clear. Let's take the following call sequence, for example:

1. nsXULDocument.cpp has a nsXULDocument::ResumeWalk() method.
2. It calls LoadScript() [around line:3004].
3. LoadScript() calls NS_NewStreamLoader [nsXULDocument.cpp, line 
   3440].
4. NS_NewStreamLoader calls NS_NewChannel() [nsNetUtil.h, line:593].
5. NS_NewChannel() then calls ioservice->NewChannelFromURI() 
   [nsNetUtil.h, line:226].
6. NewChannelFromURI() calls NewChannelFromURIWithProxyFlags() 
   [nsIOService.cpp line:596].
7. NewChannelFromURIWithProxyFlags() calls handler->newChannel() which 
   is resolved at runtime to become nsChromeProtocolHandler->newChannel() 
   [nsChromeProtocolHandler.cpp, line:182].
8. This in turn calls ioServ->NewChannelFromURI() 
   [nsChromeProtocolHandler.cpp, line:196].
9. Step 6 is repeated.
10. Step 7 is repeated, however, at different times, it can load 
    different handlers based on the protocol (chrome, jar, file etc.)

My intention for describing the above call sequence was to set up the 
context for my problem. I want to know when "chrome://" protocol is 
used, and when it is used, I want to process the input stream. For 
example, if Firefox is loading a script like "chrome://package/content/ 
script.js" I want to intercept the file when it is accessed from the 
disk. After intercepting the file, I might change it's contents, or 
dump the file's content in a folder of my choice.

So, whenever Firefox reads a file (using a method like fread(), 
probably, I would like to know that as well), I would like to determine whether the read request was from the chrome protocol or not, and at that moment I can make some changes to the file based on my needs. Any helps regarding this?

Comment: I think that the only way would be to replace the `chrome://` protocol handler - but that would quickly become a huge mess. For performance reasons, the `chrome://` protocol no longer provides a way for you to "peek inside".

Comment: Hmm, I understand. I assume the general interface of Necko is where the concrete protocol information get lost.

Answer (score 0):

For those who've stumbled here curious about the 'chrome' protocol, here are some references that may be handy:
- [Chrome Protocol, part of SPDY](http://www.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-whitepaper) 
- [Lets make the web faster project](http://code.google.com/speed/)